# Give class to image when option is picked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know which option is picked for example option with `value=2` is picked and give `z-index` to image `class="2"` with javascript.

```
<div id="images1">
  <img class="1" src="paper.png">
  <img class="2" src="sciessors.png">
  <img class="3" src="rock.png">
</div>

<select class="player1">
  <option value="1">Choose your pick</option>
  <option value="1">Rock</option>
  <option value="2">Sciessors </option>
  <option value="3">Paper</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hint : onchange of player1 check value on based  on that you can apply css

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I have no idea what to try that's why I use stackoverflow otherwise I wouldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to do this. Try this way

```
$('.player1').change(function(){
$('#images1 img').removeClass('active');
    var value = $(this).val();
    //console.log(value);
    $(this).parents().find('#images1').find('.' + value ).addClass('active')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/d8xz2a7u/9/

Answer (score 1):

As long as the `class` (the `1`, `2` and `3` class-names) and the `value` of the selected `option` from the dropdown (`select`) match then get the last selected `img` (that has a specified `class` let's say "selected-img") to remove from it the "selected-img" `class` then just add it to the `img` that has a class matches the selected `option` value (`option` value = `2` => "selected-img" `class` is added to `img` that has `2` as one of its class-names). Also, this is done into a `change` event handler applied to the dropdown.

Here's a demo to illustrate, it has some helpful comments that may assist you when reading :

> As changing the `z-index` rule for the `img` that has a `class` matching the selected `option` value cannot be distinguishable (in fact it can be done if we just stack these images on top of each others and then the one to appear is the one having the highest `z-index`), I'll just make appear an image based on the selected `option` value that matches the image's `class`.

```js
/**
* imgs: the images in the page under "div#images1".
* selectBox: the dropdown menu.
**/
const imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('#images1 img')],
  selectBox = document.getElementById('player1');

/** add "change" event handler to the dropdown **/
selectBox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  /** get the image that has the class "selected-img" if found **/
  const lastSelected = imgs.filter(i => i.classList.contains('selected-img'));

  /** remove the "selected-img" class from that image **/
  lastSelected[0] && lastSelected[0].classList.remove('selected-img');

  /** add "selected-img" class to the image that has a class match the selected option value **/
  imgs.filter(i => i.classList.contains(selectBox[selectBox.selectedIndex].value))[0].classList.add('selected-img');
});
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

img.selected-img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- for demo purposes I replaced the "src" of the "img" tags with some images from imgur so you can see the changes -->
<div id="images1">
  <img class="1" src="https://i.imgur.com/sduLRvf.jpg">
  <img class="2" src="https://i.imgur.com/tXtwrPd.jpg">
  <img class="3" src="https://i.imgur.com/QguApMA.jpg">
</div>

<!-- added an ID for the select tag so it'll be easier to reference it with avaScript -->
<select id="player1" class="player1">
  <!-- first option is disabled and selected by default as its role to have an info message "choose your pick" -->
  <option selected disabled>Choose your pick</option>
  <option value="1">Paper</option>
  <option value="2">Sciessors </option>
  <option value="3">Rock</option>
</select>
```

A better approach to achieve your task is to not rely on the match between a `class` of an image and the selected `option` value as `class` is related to styling in the end, instead you could use a `data-*` attribute on each image that has a value that can match one of the dropdown `option`s value (instead of `class="3"` we'll use `data-index=3` where `index` can be changed per your requirement).

Here's another demo in which we'll try to make appear an image with `z-index` rule (even though you didn't provide suffisant clarification of the way you'll use the `z-index` rule) :

```js
const imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('#images1 img')],
  selectBox = document.getElementById('player1');

selectBox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const lastSelected = imgs.filter(i => i.classList.contains('selected-img'));
  lastSelected[0] && lastSelected[0].classList.remove('selected-img');

  /** add "selected-img" class to the image that has "data-index" matches the selected option from the dropdown **/
  imgs.filter(i => i.dataset.index == selectBox[selectBox.selectedIndex].value)[0].classList.add('selected-img');
});
```

```css
#images1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.selected-img {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!-- now instead of class 1, 2, 3 we have data-index that holds a value that can match an option's value from the dropdown -->
<div id="images1">
  <img data-index="1" src="https://i.imgur.com/sduLRvf.jpg">
  <img data-index="2" src="https://i.imgur.com/tXtwrPd.jpg">
  <img data-index="3" src="https://i.imgur.com/QguApMA.jpg">
</div>

<select id="player1" class="player1">
  <option selected disabled>Choose your pick</option>
  <option value="1">Paper</option>
  <option value="2">Sciessors </option>
  <option value="3">Rock</option>
</select>
```

In the end, here's some helpful links :

> Learn more about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function.
>
> Learn more about [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function.
>
> Learn more about [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) attribute.
>
> Learn more about [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) attribute.